# Elasticsearch - JSON field mapping explosion

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 6.6 and trying to index document of form:

```
{
   "key1": "-value-",
   "key2": "-value-",
   "attributes":{
       "code":"-value-"
       .....
   },
   ......
}
```

The problem is with json field 'attributes' since multiple records can have different/same set of keys as well as same key can have values of different datatype. For example, record1 has attributes.code=123 and record2 has attributes.code="A123".

Due to this, while indexing large records, ES throws mapping/parsing error since it dynamically assigns datatype based on the first record being indexed. My data is such that, it is hard to determine schema of 'attributes' field since it is dynamic. Also, the attribute 'json' structure is necessary as I will be aggregating on attributes key-value while creating reports.

Is there any way to avoid mapping explosion only for json fields? Also, what is the correct way to handle such situation?

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm very sad that nobody answered you. :(